# Recursive generic function for Cartesian product in Python

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I'm looking for a way to implement a recursive function to get a generic cartesian product of the same list n times without using the itertools package.
The function should get as parameters the list and the n times.

Output Example:

```
>>> l = [0, 2]
>>> print([(x,y) for x in l for y in l])

>>> [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
```

But also:

```
>>> l = [0,2]
>>> print([(x,y,z) for x in l for y in l for z in l])
>>> [(0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 2),(0, 2, 0),(0, 2, 2),(2, 0, 0),(2, 0, 2),(2, 2, 0),(2, 2, 2)]
```

Or

```
>>> l = [4,5,8]
>>> print([(x,y) for x in l for y in l])
>>> [(4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 8), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 8), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 8)]
```

Etc..

I wanna generalize this for every generic list and every n-tuple.
I found different ways to implement this iteratively but none with recursion. Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def cartesian_product(lst, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return [tuple() for _ in lst]
    return [(x,) + t for t in cartesian_product(lst, n - 1) for x in lst]
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. +1 from me

Comment: it should be mentioned that this eagerly computes _all_ products before any result is returned. for large inputs in particular problems this could mean a lot of wasted computations. with python's strong support for generators and iterables throughout the standard library, i think it's best to use generators for this. i will add that the function could be more flexible if it could compute products of different lists, not just a single list with itself.

Comment: another issue is `cartesian_product` as defined here is not a [total function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalFunction.html). if the function is called with `n = 0` or `n < 1` it will cause a stack overflow. by simply rewriting your base case to `n <= 0` and `return [tuple() for _ in lst]` you make the function behave correctly for all possible inputs. recursion is a functional heritage and so paying attention to these small details will yield the best results.

Answer (score 1):

**intuitive**

Better than using a fixed integer, I think `product(t)` should take a list of iterables -

1. if the input `t` is empty, yield the empty product, `()`
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one iterable. for all `p` in the result of the sub-problem `product(t[1:])`, for all `v` in the first iterable `t[0]`, prepend `v` to `p` and yield

```py
def product(t):
  if not t:
    yield ()                   # 1. no iterables
  else:
    for p in product(t[1:]):   # 2. at least one iterable
      for v in t[0]:
        yield (v, *p)
```

My multiplying the input by `*2` you can still control the output of `product` -

```py
for p in product([[1,2]] * 2):
  print(p)
```

```py
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
```

Now let's multiply by `*3` -

```py
for p in product([[1,2]] * 3):
  print(p)
```

```py
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2)
```

**flexible**

Since any iterable can be used, you can mix/match to your liking -

```py
for p in product([range(2), [3,4], "hi", (9,)]):
  print(p)
```

```py
(0, 3, 'h', 9)
(1, 3, 'h', 9)
(0, 4, 'h', 9)
(1, 4, 'h', 9)
(0, 3, 'i', 9)
(1, 3, 'i', 9)
(0, 4, 'i', 9)
(1, 4, 'i', 9)
```

**efficient**

Use of a generator makes `product` efficient for use in problems involving combinatorics. Generators allow us to pause/cancel and provide early exit once a desired result is found -

```py
def solveTriangle(min, max):
  for (x,y,z) in product([list(range(min, max))] * 3):
    if x ** 2 + y ** 2 == z ** 2:
      return (x,y,z)               # <- return stops generator
  return None
```

```py
print(solveTriangle(10,30))
```

```py
(16, 12, 20)
```

**itertools**

Note the `itertools` module provides [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as a built-in function. It's fun to implement `product` as an exercise, but if you plan to use this in production code, the built-in function probably offers the best performance.